# Unable to stop the propogation of events in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a condition where I have simple dropdown menu

```
handleDropdown = (e) => {
    if (e.type === "focus") {
      console.log("inside dropdown focus");
      this.setState({ dropDownDis: "block" })
    } else if (e.type === "blur") {
      console.log("inside dropdown blur");
      this.setState({ dropDownDis: "none" })
    }
  }

 logout = (e) => {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("inside logout")
  }
```

When I click on Logout, The menu closes but logout method doesn't calls.

**html**

```
  <div className="header-user">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="dropdown-button"
                ref={this.myRef}
                onFocus={this.handleDropdown}
                onBlur={this.handleDropdown}              
              >
              <img src="/img/headericon.png" alt="no header icon" />
              </button>

              <div className="dropdown-menu" style={{ display: dropDownDis }}>

              <ul className="sidebar-list">
               <li>
                <img src="../img/user.png"/> <a href="#">My Profile </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                <img src="../img/order.png"/><a href="#">Order </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                <img src="../img/account.png"/> <a href="#">My Account </a>
              </li>
              <li>
               <img src="../img/logout.png"/> <a onClick={this.logout}>Log Out </a>
              </li>
             </ul>

            </div>
   </div>
```

On clicking the logout I can see the console as shown in below image

[image: console image]

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: @Nipun Jain No I didn't got any error, but the only thing I can see is the drop down console even when I'm clicking on logout, it seems that the I haven't used the stop propagation in right way

Comment: Shouldnt you call your parent component logout method?

Comment: @G_S have a look at the edited query

Answer (score 0):

If the `handleDropdownOptions` is in a child component, you have to pass the `logout` function as a prop to the child component and call it inside `handleDropdownOptions`

```
handleDropdownOptions = () => {
    console.log("-------dropdown------");
    this.props.logout();
}
```

Comment: The handleDropdownOptions() is here to only control the drop down actions i.e. open/close , after drop down opens the child component renders in this.props.links, after that the logout come into action and that too when user will click on logout, but the question is that even clicking logout  doesn't work here it only hits it's parent method

Comment: @Adarsh but the log only has the `-------dropdown------`, why does not have the `-----logout-----`? I think it is because the `logout` function is not being invoked.

Comment: @Adarsh can you please provide the complete code? I tried this in [codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-waterfall-uknex?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) i it is logging the `logout` message.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the parent logout's function in the handleDropdownOptions's child function (in your case).